# Resizable child "ImGui"

Tags: imgui

I'm having a problem with my project where I can't get my `ImGui::Beginchild` to be resizable like `ImGui::Begin()`

I found other ways to do this but it was not to my liking: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/319

EXAMPLE CODE :

```
ui::Begin("title"){

ui::BeginChild("child title", child_size);// resize this child_size when i click the bottom of the child and move

{    
ui:Text("example");

}       

ui::EndChild();


}

ui::End();
```